# Set the value of a BehaviourSubject from an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Just looking to see if there is a better way of doing this:

```
this.observable$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((observableValue) => {
  this.behaviourSubject$.next(observableValue);
});
```

When I say *better*, I am thinking without having to subscribe to the original observable and use `take(1)`

I was looking at `startWith`:

```
this.behaviourSubject$.pipe(
  startWith(this.observable$)
)
```

But `startWith` does not accept an observable.

Comment: You can use this `concat(this.observable$.pipe(take(1)), this.behaviourSubject$)` if you want the first value to always come from `this.observable$`

Comment: concat(this.observable$.pipe(take(1)), this.behaviourSubject$) has the issue that the second value will always be the initial value of the behavior subject.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, to combine your requirement into one stream

```
this.observable$.pipe(
first(),
tap(()=>this.behaviourSubject$.next(observableValue))
switchMapTo(this.behaviourSubject$))
```